# Show the UI when loggin in to google account

Tags: android

How do I show the login popup u see when entering game apps? the one that drops from top of the screen and goes away?
I tried using google play api but it doesnt seem to create it:

```
fun initGoogleClientAndSignin() {
    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(
        GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build())

    googleSignInClient?.silentSignIn()?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            achievementClient = Games.getAchievementsClient(this,
                task.result!!)
            leaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this,
                task.result!!)
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "signInError", task.exception)
        }
    }
}
```

i can see task.isSuccessful is true, but the popuo doesnt appear

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the Google Play Games integration?

Comment: I guess it is, thanks :)